# VBA - Count cells that are hidden and have specific value

Tags: excel, vba, hidden, countif

I'm trying to figure out how I can write a VBA code that counts how many of the cells in my range are hidden AND have a specific value.

I've tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
Sub Count_hidden_ABC()
Dim s As Long
Dim Rg As Range
Set Rg = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G8:G255")
s = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Rg, "ABC", Rg, SpecialValues(12))
```

or

```
Sub Count_hidden_ABC()
Dim s As Long
Dim Rg As Range
Set Rg = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G8:G255")
s = Rg.SpecialCells(12).Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rg, "ABC")
```

Anyone has a clue how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Special Cells feat. Areas

- When you are selecting SpecialCells(**12**) or
  SpecialCells(**xlCellTypeVisible**) you are selecting the visible
  cells not the invisible that you need.
- Don't know exactly what's going on, but it seems like **CountIf**
  doesn't work with non-contiguous ranges.
- So you could loop through the ranges in a non-contiguous range using
  **Areas**.

### The Code

```
Sub Count_hidden_ABC()

    Dim s As Long
    Dim Rg As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Set Rg = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G8:G255")

    For Each rng In Rg.SpecialCells(12).Areas
        s = s + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, "ABC")
    Next

    s = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rg, "ABC") - s
    'Debug.Print s

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code as a base, it counts hidden cells with value of `"ABC"` in specified range:

```
Sub CountHiddenCellsInRange()
    Dim rng As Range, hiddenCells As Long, c As Range
    hiddenCells = 0
    Set rng = Range("A1:B5")
    For Each c In rng
        If (Rows(c.Row).Hidden Or Columns(c.Column).Hidden) And c.Value = "ABC" Then hiddenCells = hiddenCells + 1
    Next
    MsgBox hiddenCells
End Sub
```